# Response body gets dropped when coming through HLB(HardwareLoadbalancer) randomly

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We used wso2esb 4..8.1.
We are facing issue when moved into the production some of the requests from client is getting 404 page not found error .Where as everything is working in dev environment
We are facing same issue like above description the difference is we are using F5 Hard ware load balance.
we are able to see request and response printed in wso2carbon.log but client is not getting response and resulting 404 error code.
Please be informed that this problem is happening only for certain requests only not for all.
We tried to reproduce this scenario using Jmeter and Soap UI but did not face this problem. Our doubt is response being dropped going through HLB.
Please suggest.

Comment: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-2590

Comment: Major issue in wso2 product not able to move in production customer rejected this product. because of this issue